# Every time I connect my iPad, iTunes wants to back it up

Tags: itunes, ipad

Every time I connect my iPad, iTunes wants to back it up. I don't want to back it up, I just want to transfer some files into an app.

This is with the Windows version of iTunes and I keep aborting the back up, because it's very slow. I want iTunes to stop auto-backing it up, is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Under Edit / Preferences / Devices, check the "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically" item.